# The solution of $Ax=b$ if $Ax=0$ has nontrivial solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose A is a matrix with order $n$, for $Ax=0$, there is at least one nontrivial solution, so for any vector $b$ with n components, how many solutions of $Ax=b$

Comment: Either $0$ or infinitely many.  What do you mean by "order $n$"?

Answer (score 2):

Either infinitely many, or none. If there exists one solution to $Ax=b$, then take your nontrivial solution $v$ to $Av=0$ and add it to $x$.

$$A(v+x) = Av+Ax= 0+b=b$$

Any scalar multiple of $v$ will also work. But there may be no solutions, such as

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$